# Javascript set the label text resetting when within a updatepanel and wizard

Tags: javascript, updatepanel, wizard

I have a couple controls inside a wizard that is wrapped in an updatepanel.  When I set the innerHTML on the label to province it sets it back to to State:

my dropdownlist I am calling my javascript function  onchange="javascript:ValidateCountry();"  this all works I can see if gets called it sets the value but when I run all the way the page resets the values back?

```
function ValidateCountry(sender, args) {

        var ddlGuestCountry = document.getElementById('<%= ui_ddl_GuestCountry.ClientID %>');
        var lblGuestState = document.getElementById('<%= ui_lbl_GuestState.ClientID %>');


        if (ddlGuestCountry.value != "USA") {
            lblGuestState.innerHTML = "Province:";


        }
        else {
            lblGuestState.innerHTML = "State:";

        }

    }
```

Update: I commented out the update panel and the value is still getting reset back to State on the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it Forgot to change the autopostback to false on the dropdownlist.